# Update your CSS file after saving changes in SCSS file (to work like ScoutApp)

Tags: ubuntu, sass

I have two folders: (SCSS input, CSS output folder)

### CSS

- main.css

### SCSS

- _base (file.scss, file.scss, file.scss ...)
- _pages (just like _base)
- _elements (just like others)
- _parts (just like others)

In SCSS folder I have alot of folders and files with .scss extensions. I just installed Linux Ubuntu for the first time and it's all new to me. When I was on Windows I used ScoutApp (https://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) which updated CSS file whenever I made change on any of my SCSS files and saved them.

Which command should I use to make same or similar effect?

I would also like to put this command on hotkey (shortcut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are editors and IDEs for developers which offer such a functionality, for example I use tools from Jetbrains like RubyMine on OS X which offers a file viewer feature. If you save your scss file then it compiles it to a css file.

And there are GUI-Tools which offer this functionality as well. But they all use a tool in the background, you could use via the terminal yourself instead: sass. If you install (or already have installed sass on your ubuntu) you could do something like this:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

This would watch the `style.scss` file and compile it to `style.css` the moment you save the file.

You could check if you have installed sass by typing `sass -v` into your terminal. If you get an error it probably is not installed.

As I mentioned, there are GUI tools as well. Koala (http://koala-app.com/) is available for Linux and Open Source, there are other tools as well but you might have to pay for them. More information on this you can get here: http://sass-lang.com/install

Comment: sass --watch style.scss:style.css is on file level. I would like it to be on folder level. However, my main scss file has includes from all other scss files. If I save changes on these files  and run this command. Would it make change I expect? And btw, how does it know which files I want to change if there are more projects with same file names?

Comment: You can use sass on folders, too. Like `sass --watch <input folder>:<output folder>`. If those are your current working directory it would be okay to input `sass watch .:.`. But you can create a single scss file which `@includes` all the other files and then "watch" it. This will create only one single .css file from all the others included in your project.

Comment: Thank you. I hope you wouldn't mind if I ask you this question since I have only few hours of experience on Linux.  Where do I begin path? (my project is in this directory:  var/www/html/   (here I have  scss folder and css folder)

Comment: The file name only matters if you do it file by file. Then you would have to specify the input file and the output position too, like: `sass --watch /my/path/style.scss:/your/path/style.css` and so on. It would not recognize that there is more than one file with the same name instead you tell it. Because `/path/a/style.scss` is different from `/path/b/style.scss`, though the files have the same name. You should make a copy of your work and start experimenting with sass. That's the way I normally learn things. ^^

Comment: There is a wonderful command for this, to make sure you always use the right path. Just change directory, till you "are" in the folder your files are in, then type `pwd` to the terminal. This outputs the path you're in. And that one you should use with every command you want to be used, may it be sass or others.

Comment: I used `sass --watch /var/www/html/scss/main.scss:/var/www/html/css/main.css` and it worked. However when I make change on document and save, nothing happens. And then when I call this command again it updates file. How can I automatize it? I added it onto hotkey (ctrl+alt+s) so whenever I save file (ctrl+s) i also press that hotkey, but it would be nice if I only needed to save file and not press command hotkey.

Comment: @Kunok Unfortunately, when you close the terminal or restart your computer, then you have to run the command again. You could search for particular solutions to "daemonize" sass (which means "run it in the background") with Ubuntu. In Linux you could add a Script to `/etc/init.d` which is run at startup, so you won't have to start this yourself. But this is beyond my knowledge especially because you are using Ubuntu and I'm on a Mac. I hope you can go on from here.

Comment: Isn't that command supposed to  update CSS file from SCSS changes all by itself once it's called?

Comment: @Kunok If you start a command in a terminal and quit the terminal, you quit the command, too, because it was bound to the session which was created in the terminal window. That is, why some people make startup scripts and start and stop scripts on their computers startup, those scripts are bound to the session of your computer, not the individual terminal one's. Maybe this can help you to make a startup script at your Ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: I am aware the command stops if terminal is closed. However, the problem is that it doesn't update CSS file itself. It only makes update once it is called, and after that to make a change, I need to call it again. The second issue is that it takes like 30 seconds to make change.

Comment: Are you using a particular editor for development? For example there is a plugin for sublime which runs the sass command on file save. Here is described how to use it: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-text-compiling-sass/ Maybe this can solve your problems. And yes people tend to say sass is not the fastest solution. It's based on Ruby. Maybe you should try Grunt, it uses libsass, which is based on C++. https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass

Comment: I use Atom text editor, I am going to search for the plugin. I am kinda in love with Ruby lately, don't wanna cheat on her yet :)

Comment: Here is the link to the plugin for Atom: https://atom.io/packages/sass-autocompile

Comment: I also found this one trough Atom app itself. This one doesn't require third party software. https://atom.io/packages/sass-watch